# Are comparability graphs closed under vertex identification?

Tags: graph-theory, order-theory

Are comparability graphs closed under edge contractions?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparability_graph

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_contraction#Vertex_identification

It seems like they are, since any function identifying vertices would correspond to a monotone map between two orientations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear whether you're asking about edge contractions or about all vertex identifications (your title and your question disagree) but the answer for both of them is no.

A cycle of length $6$ is a comparability graph, for example for the poset with elements $\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{2,3\}$ ordered by inclusion, as shown below.

[image]

If you contract any edge, you get a cycle of length $5$, which is not a comparability graph because it's not perfect.

Or, for a self-contained demonstration: suppose that $C_5$ were a comparability graph. Orient each edge $vw$ to point in the direction $v \to w$ when $v < w$. Because the cycle is odd, the edges cannot alternate direction all the way around the cycle: there must be two consecutive edges $uv, vw$ oriented $u \to v, v \to w$ or $u \gets v, v \gets w$. But now, transitivity demands that the edge $uw$ should also exist, and it doesn't: contradiction!

Comment: How is a cycle of length $6$ a comparability graph? The example you gave is of length $3$.

Comment: Why with $3$ elements? There are $6$ elements and the cycle goes $1 - 12 - 2 - 23 - 3 - 13 - 1$.

Comment: That's not the comparability graph. The vertices of the graph are the elements of the poset, and the poset I'm describing has $6$ elements. There is an edge between any two elements that are comparable. For example, $\{1\}$ is comparable to $\{1,2\}$ and $\{1,3\}$, but not to $\{2\}$, $\{3\}$, or $\{2,3\}$.

Comment: By a comparability graph of a poset $P=(X,\leq)$ I mean the unique graph $G_P$ such that we have both $V(G_P)=X$ and $E(G_P)=\{\{u,v\}:u<v\}$

Comment: That's also what I mean. I want you take $X = \{ \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{2,3\}\}$ and $\le$ to be $\subseteq$. This has $6$ vertices.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106096/discussion-between-ethan-and-misha-lavrov).